# passing a BLOB to oracleDBH fro node-oracledb

Tags: node.js, oracle

I have db package method with the following signature

```
PROCEDURE p_add_rate_tables (p_in IN OUT BLOB, p_message IN OUT VARCHAR2);
```

now from node-oracledb to pass the params I pass the following code

```
const mergedTrunks = trunks.map(t =>
                `["${t.xxx1}", "${t.xxx2}", "${t.xxx3}"]`
            ).join(', ');
            const buffer = Buffer.from(`[${mergedTrunks}]`);
            const bindvars = {

                p_in: {val: buffer, type: oracledb.BUFFER, dir: oracledb.BIND_INOUT},
                p_message: {type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_INOUT}
            };
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                connection.execute(
                    `
    begin
    ${config.database}.pkg_trunks.p_add_rate_tables (:p_in, :p_message);
    commit;
    end;`,
                    bindvars)
```

But no matter what I do and how I play with the parameters - on the DB side they are not parsed back correctly - I cannot see why on the DB, or at least our DB guys can't.

it is not a formation issue - since if I take the actual string and put it into oracle utl_raw.cast_to_raw - then everything works perfectly.

ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for someone who encounters this question/issue.
Obviously it is not about templates or data - as no body would rebuild the schema we have ( it is a strongly complex DB schema that 2 DBA's barely maintain)

The issue was not in the actual serialization, but rather on the way back!
as you can see the variables are INOUT vars,

```
p_in: {val: buffer, type: oracledb.BUFFER, dir: oracledb.BIND_INOUT}
```

BUT what happens if the variable on its way back - is bigger than the one on the way in ? BOOM, an unexplained error.
So you need to specify the size of the buffer to get the element back, it is easily done with

```
maxSize: 4000
```

so the full definition should have been

```
p_in: {val: buffer, type: oracledb.BUFFER, dir: oracledb.BIND_INOUT, maxSize: 4000},
```

and thats it - everything works, the issue is exactly the same whatever you use CLOB or BLOB as there is a need for buffer size definition

Comment: To help future searchability, what was the 'unexplained error' you saw?

Comment: @ChristopherJones thanks for taking a look
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: raw variable length too long
ORA-06512: at line 3

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick test of your map:

```
const trunks = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
const mergedTrunks = trunks.map(t =>
                `["${t.xxx1}", "${t.xxx2}", "${t.xxx3}"]`);

console.log(mergedTrunks); // ["["undefined", "undefined", "undefined"]", "["undefined", "undefined", "undefined"]", "["undefined", "undefined", "undefined"]"]
```

Here's a slightly modified version that uses the template literal correctly:

```
const trunks = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
const mergedTrunks = trunks.map(t =>
                `["${t}.xxx1", "${t}.xxx2", "${t}.xxx3"]`);

console.log(mergedTrunks); // ["["test1.xxx1", "test1.xxx2", "test1.xxx3"]", "["test2.xxx1", "test2.xxx2", "test2.xxx3"]", "["test3.xxx1", "test3.xxx2", "test3.xxx3"]"]
```

Start by fixing that and see where it goes.

Comment: Add - the idea was not behind the data, I am very well aware I put here mock data - which might be incorrect. its the actual transaction and data translation thjat is problematic

Comment: You didn't provide mock data (trunks), you provided incorrectly written templates. I suggested you fix them. Please provide more details regarding "on the DB side they are not parsed back correctly" and "if I take the actual string and put it into oracle utl_raw.cast_to_raw - then everything works perfectly".